# Android - Change a layout attribute on a button click

Tags: java, android, layout, textview, selector

I have a problem here.

I have a large text, that doesn't fit in the screen... So in the layout XML I have put this string:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Ok, but now I want to make this TextView clickable and when I click it, I want to change the layout XML code to:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

So the text roll and people will read it.

I've searched lots os questions but none has answered that, just for 'drawable' things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

on textView Click.